# Why do I get the error [Unknown custom element: did you register the component correctly?] when I try to nest local components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue and I'm trying to organize my app a little bit. I originally had 2 components: `PageTable` and `PageRow`. When nested, they worked just fine. However, when I use `PageTable` with a new component `Title` in `AllPages`, I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <page-title> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <AllPages>
       <Root>

------------------------

vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <page-table> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <AllPages>
       <Root>
```

Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be awesome.

**JS File**

```
//Components:
var AllPages = {
  components: {
    'page-title': Title,
    'page-table': PageTable
  },
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <page-title></page-title>
      <div class="table-responsive-sm" id="pageChart">
          <page-table></page-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

var Title = {
  name: 'page-title',
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  template: `
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>{{ title }}:</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

var PageTable = {
  data: function() {
    return{
      pages: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.fetchPages();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPages: function(e) {
        this.pages = [];
        var self = this;

        console.log('beginning function');

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

          // For a successful response
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            self.pages = response.data;

            }
          };

        xhttp.open('GET', this.$parent.createReqURL('admin/videos/all/'), true);
        xhttp.send(); //Data needs to be sent in string format (content type set above)
      },
      editPage: function(query){
        console.log(query);
        window.location.href = '../admin/create.html?' + query;
      },
      loadDetails: function(){

      }
    },
    components: {
      'page-row': PageRow
    },
    template:`
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr class="row">
          <th class="col">Slug</th>
          <th class="col">Artist Name</th>
          <th class="col">Tour</th>
          <th class="col-sm-1 alignCenter">Edit</th>
          <th class="col-sm-1 alignCenter">Details</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <page-row
          v-for="page in pages"
          v-bind:key="page.slug"
          v-bind:page="page">
        </page-row>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    `
}

var PageRow = {
  props: ['page'],
  template: `
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col"><a href="https://exclusive.livenation.com/" target=_blank>{{ page.slug }}</a></td>
    <td class="col">{{ page.artist }}</td>
    <td class="col">{{ page.tour }}</td>
    <td class="col-sm-1 alignCenter icon"><img src="styles/images/icon_edit.svg" alt=""></td>
    <td class="col-sm-1 alignCenter icon"><img src="styles/images/icon_info.svg" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  `
}


//App
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentComponent: 'all-pages',
  },
  components: {
    'all-pages': AllPages,
  },
  mounted: function(){
  },
  methods: {
    createReqURL: function(path) {
      var baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';
      return baseURL + path;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <universal-header></universal-header>
      <component :is="currentComponent"></component>
      <universal-footer></universal-footer>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import and add the component to the components section, or register it globally.

It looks like you already added `PageRow`

```
components: {
      'page-row': PageRow
    },
```

In your Vue Component

```
// import if not defined locally
import PageTable from '@/components/PageTabe.vue'

{ 
 components:{PageTable, 'page-row': PageRow},
}
```

Or Globally:

```
Vue.component('PageTable', PageTable)
Vue.component('PageTitle', PageTitle)
Vue.component('PageRow', PageRow)
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

So in `PageTable`, I registered `PageRow`
In `All Pages`, I registered `PageTable` and `Title`

```
var AllPages = {
  components: {
    'page-title': Title,
    'page-table': PageTable,
  },
```

But I'm still getting the same error?

Comment: @NupurMathur Register them all globally, confirm it works, and then go from there. I updated solution with all components registering globally.

Comment: Thanks @StevenSpungin. Just registered them all globally and i'm still getting the error for <all-pages>
Vue.component('page-title', Title);
Vue.component('page-table', PageTable);
Vue.component('page-row', PageRow);
Vue.component('all-pages', AllPages);

Comment: Now, make sure each component has a name member. You are missing some.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense here =/, but when i define the global component, isn't the first argument the name?
Vue.component('all-pages', AllPages)

Comment: Look at your component def for `Title`.  There is a name property in the component options.  I have seen those create unexpected results, especially if 2 different components declare the same name!  I found that out after some unexpected 'cut-and-pastes'...

Comment: var PageTable = { name:'page-table', // <--------
  data: function() {
    return{
      pages: []
    }
  },